# Sending MapboxMap from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mapbox

so what I'm trying to do is use the same MapboxMap in 2 different activities. It's proving to be a bit difficult to pass on to the other. i haven't been able to figure out how to do it through intent (using putExtra) as I know it needs to be either Parcelable or Serializable but I don't know how to set that up.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: MapboxMap instances are linked to the underlying MapView, you can't reuse them